# Extra character added to the output of an array when looping through it

Tags: bash, for-loop, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

a=coop; b=(`echo $a | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'`)
for i in ${b[@]}    
do    
  echo -n $i

  count=$((count+1))

  if [ $count = 2 ]; then    
    echo -e '\e[0;34m'$i
    shift
    echo -ne $*'\e[0m'
  fi
done
```

Output: cooop (the middle one is in blue). What I want the script to do is show the exact word stored in the variable named "a". But as you can see, another "o" is added next to "p". So how can i go about removing the extra letter?

Comment: it seems you didnt describe what you really want to do, since "outputting the characters of the variable" would be finished with echo -n $i

Comment: What I want to do is keep the blue "o" in the third position and remove the extra "o" just added next to it on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

blue='\e[0;34m'
nc='\e[0m'

a=coop
b=($(echo $a | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'))
count=0
for i in ${b[@]}; do
    if [ $count = 2 ]; then
        echo -ne "${blue}${i}"
        echo -ne "${nc}"
    else
        echo -n "$i"
    fi
    count=$((count+1))
done
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked well. I still dont get why count=0 outside the loop is so significant

Comment: It's just a good practice to set your variables. In this case since arrays are indexed at 0 it helps

Comment: Thanks so much. one more question, is it possible to assign an variable for the output of the for loop ? BTW, I did mark your answer :D

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I did not understand the question.

Comment: So I already got the output "coop" correctly. Now, put it into an variable...how can I do that?

Comment: I'm thinking about this line: > name which perhaps stays at the end of the loop. But its a file, not a variable...I can later cat it and store in a variable...However, I want to do it directly.